# Is there is any oracle function equivalent to mysql_query( set names 'utf8' )

Tags: php, oracle, utf-8

We are using PHP and Oracle.

```
Connection string :
$connect_db = oci_connect($username, $password, $host_db, 'AL32UTF8');
```

Also in php code.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

My Problem is inside the php page, it is converted to regional language. but When it is stored into Oracle db it is stored like '¿¿¿¿¿¿'.

How can we solve this?
Any Oracle function is available equivalent to mysql_query( set names 'utf8' ).

Previously we are using UTF8 instead of "AL32UTF8" in connection string.

Comment: Is the database column `VARCHAR2` or `NVARCHAR2`?

Comment: We are using VARCHAR2

Comment: If you run `SELECT * FROM v$NLS_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER LIKE 'NLS_%CHARACTERSET';` what do you get for the character sets?

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET value= AL32UTF8 and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET value=  AL16UTF16

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET value= AL32UTF8 and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET value= AL16UTF16.                                 Is there is any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this format
    $connect_db = oci_connect($username, $password, $host_db, 'AL32UTF8');